# Perform a regex $in query with PyMongo on _id field

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

In mongo shell, I can do the following

```
db.getCollection('my-collection').find({_id: {$in: [/^id0$/, /^id0#spr#/, /^id1$/, /^id1#spr#/]}})
```

But I can't find how to do this in PyMongo, there doesn't seem to be any equivelant.

I've tried re.compile, and `$in [{"$regex": ...}]`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for an answer to this, the only way I could find to emulate the mongo shell version (making sure it uses the index) was to use an `$or` expression like so

```
db["my-collection"].find(
    {
        "$or": [
            {"_id": {"$regex": "^id0$"}},
            {"_id": {"$regex": "^id0#spr#"}},
            {"_id": {"$regex": "^id1$#"}},
            {"_id": {"$regex": "^id1#spr#"}},
        ]
    }
)
```